# Issues with AppConfig inside a custom appender in log4j2

Tags: java, app-config, log4j2

I have migrated a custom appender to log4j2. The appender was successfully using AppConfig.findMap before migration and code was working fine. But post migration I am getting an error saying -

```
AppConfig not initialized yet
    [junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Thoughts ? Has this anything to do with the new plugin annotation which is required for custom appenders in log4j2 ?

```
@Plugin(name = "MyAppender")
```